# How can I make the react component completely disappear from the dom so that the animation is preserved?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, modal-dialog

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./components/Modal/Modal";
export default function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <p className="ppp">Sample text</p>
      <div className="modal_menu_wrap">
        <div className="modal_menu">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setShowModal(true);
            }}
            className="open-btn"
          >
            Open/Close
          </button>
          <Modal active={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.css

```
.open-btn {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.open-btn:hover {
  scale: 1.05;
}
.modal_menu_wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
.modal_menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Modal.jsx

```
import styles from "./modal.module.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Modal({ active, setShowModal }) {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);
  const closeModal = () => {
    setShowContent(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowModal(false);
    }, 500);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      setShowContent(true);
    }
  }, [active]);
  if (!active) return null;
  return (
    <div
      className={
        showContent ? `${styles.modal} ${styles.showModal}` : `${styles.modal}`
      }
    >
      <p className="ppp"></p>
      <div onClick={closeModal} className={styles.closeBtn}>
        <span>&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

modal.module.css

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
  transform: translateY(-100vh);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.showModal {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
}
.closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
.closeBtn span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.closeBtn span:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

It is necessary that the element appears and disappears when you click on the Open / Close button, as well as if you click outside the element field. I gave the button a value `onClick={() => {setShowModal( !showModal);}}`, but in this case, the animation disappears. It is necessary that the element completely disappears from the dom. There should not be a button with a cross.
Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dust-8vj86d?file=/src/index.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply edited 2 files

#### First

made the open/close button to toggle the state by setting the new value to the inverse of the old value !showModal
in the file ` App.js`

```js
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setShowModal(!showModal);
            }}
            className="open-btn"
          >
            Open/Close
          </button>
```

---

#### Then

I removed the line `if (!active) return null;`
which is a bad approach using react! no offense but this might affect your application performance. 
And added after that a check if it is active so it removes the class

`active && showContent`
which means if active is == true then do the code on the right side of the operator
in the file `Modal.jsx`

```js
    <div
      className={
        active && showContent
          ? `${styles.modal} ${styles.showModal}`
          : `${styles.modal}`
      }
    >
```

the final code would be :

## App.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./components/Modal/Modal";

export default function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <p className="ppp">Sample text</p>

      <div className="modal_menu_wrap">
        <div className="modal_menu">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setShowModal(!showModal);
            }}
            className="open-btn"
          >
            Open/Close
          </button>

          <Modal active={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Modal.jsx

```js
import styles from "./modal.module.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Modal({ active, setShowModal }) {
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);
  const closeModal = () => {
    setShowContent(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowModal(false);
    }, 500);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      setShowContent(true);
    }
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <div
      className={
        active && showContent
          ? `${styles.modal} ${styles.showModal}`
          : `${styles.modal}`
      }
    >
      <p className="ppp"></p>

      <div onClick={closeModal} className={styles.closeBtn}>
        <span>&times;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As for return null, I have too little experience and did not know that this affects performance

Comment: But the element remains in the dom, I don't know if this is normal

Comment: You welocme bro, you may contact me at any time my contact info is in my profile.

Comment: About the the existance of the elemnt you may make a flag that is listned to by useEffect when it is no longer active, wait 1 sec then remove the item by the && operator : { hide && (<Model />) }

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to add the animation to a class.

Then set the component's styling to the state in the last frame of the animation. And as simple as that when you add the className to the component the animations happen and return to the last state by removing the className at the end of the animation. so you may edit

```js
 <button
            onClick={() => {
              {/* add the className for the open stat of the componant here  */}
              setShowModal(true);
            }}
            className="open-btn"
          >
            Open/Close
          </button>
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it, can you fix it in the demo version?

Comment: sure, I will add another answer. sorry for the latency in response